# bt-audio: Command not found

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, 16.04, bluez

I've performed the update on Ubuntu 16.04 recently and everything works fine, but I discovered that the command `bt-audio` does not work anymore. More specifically, if I enter the command the terminal output is just "Command not found". According to [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/bt-audio.1.html), it should, however, work also in 16.04.

I removed and reinstalled the following packages:

- bluez-tools
- bluez,
- pulseaudio-module-bluetooth

but that doesn't seem to solve the issue. Any suggestions?

Moreover, the command `which bt-audio` just comes back blank - i.e. the file really is not present.

The output of `dpkg -l | grep bluez-tools` is:

```
ii bluez-tools 0.2.0~20140808-5 amd64 Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
```

And the package seems to be installed from the correct sources as the output of `apt-cache policy bluez-tools` indicates:

```
bluez-tools:
  Installiert: 0.2.0~20140808-5
  Installationskandidat: 0.2.0~20140808-5
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 0.2.0~20140808-5 500
        500 es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

PS: I posted this question earlier already but the problem was not solved and I thought it to be easier to summarise the discussion from the comments into a new post and to delete the old one. So, thanks to "dufte" for working out most of the things listed above with me.

EDIT: Not even reinstalling all packages solved the issue. I'm really desperate here!

Comment: `bt-audio` doesn't exist in Xenial any more: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=bt-audio&mode=&suite=xenial&arch=any

Comment: Hm. And how do I connect from the terminal then?

Comment: If you have a new question, please [open a new question](/questions/ask). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that bt-audio is currently depreciated: https://github.com/khvzak/bluez-tools/blob/193ad6bb3db7ed2ba6b93c1ab4e1e592985e5b90/ChangeLog

You can download the older version here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/bluez-tools/0.1.38+git662e-3